# Generate Future Date Based on Dropdown List

Tags: excel, date, drop-down-menu

Have a PAT Testing Spreadsheet where I'm trying to generate a 'Next Test Date' depending on class of electrical equipment. So Class 1 is every 48 months, Class 2 every 24 months.

I have a 'Class' column which is a dropdown to select Class 1 or 2, then a 'Test Date' column which is manual entry of the last test, based on these two cells how do I generate a 'Next Test Date' column.

i.e. if I enter the test date as today then when I select Class 1 it should generate a date 4 years in the future, Class 2 a date two years ahead.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try nested `IF()` formula like

```
=TEXT(IF(A2="Class 1",DATE(YEAR(B2)+4,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)),DATE(YEAR(B2)+2,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))),"dd/mmm/yyyy")
```

[image]

Comment: @NICode Glad to know! Then please mark the answer as accepted means tick mark my answer.